# Solr indexing on custom tables

Tags: search

We are implementing apache solr search in drupal 7.. after installing the module if you run the index, the apache solr is returning results from the drupal tables (nodes,users,taxonomy,content type).
But we have created custom tables (example: product table) where apache solr is not able to index those table data.. how to make it index the custom created tables

Comment: I think your question should be directed at Search_Api, regardless of the back-end. A very long thread about indexing non-entities: https://www.drupal.org/node/1064884 and a another question related to yours: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/62808/making-custom-database-text-fields-available-for-search

Answer (score -1):

There is a patch available for this. Please refer the below link

https://www.drupal.org/node/2201309

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I've provided the link in my response